# Serial port intermittent not returning data and times out

Tags: c#, serial-port

Can't seem to get this working right.  I've tested the hardware with other programs and it works, but this code it gets an intermittent issue where no data is returned so it times out.  I've tried ReadExisting with synchronous and asynchronous, same result. Is it to do with ReadExisting and should I be using something else?

```
    private StringBuilder serialBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    private const string terminationSequence = "\r";
    private void DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = Serial.ReadExisting();
        serialBuffer.Append(data);
        var bufferString = serialBuffer.ToString();
        int index;
        do
        {
            index = bufferString.IndexOf(terminationSequence, StringComparison.Ordinal);
            if (index <= -1) continue;
            IncomingData = bufferString.Substring(0, index);
            bufferString = bufferString.Remove(0, index + terminationSequence.Length);

        } while (index > -1);
        serialBuffer = new StringBuilder(bufferString);
    }
```

I put in a few traces and it seem the event is not firing...  Here is the output and where event doesn't start before the timeout.

- Start Event
- Start do: bufferString - =00
- End Event
- Start Event
- Start do: bufferString - =007BAA
- IncomingData =007BAA
- Start do: bufferString -
- End Event
- Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in GS.SkyWatcher.dll

Comment: Does it get stuck in your `while` ? or never finds the termination sequence

Comment: using trace, looks like the event doesn't fire.  When I used synchronous it would stick on the ReadExisting line.

Comment: Turns out to be a bad cable with intermittent fails.  Apps that work are doing retries or ignoring unnecessary commands.